# How to stop a script when another button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom part builder and I have it so when a customer selects the option "Full" it executes this script

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='FirstFlangeSystem']").on("change", function(e) {
        var newValue = e.target.value;
        $("input[name='SecondFlangeSystem'][value='" + newValue + "']").prop("checked", true);
    });
    $("select[name='FirstFlangeTypeDrop']").on("change", function(e) {
        var newValues = $(this).val();
        $("select[name='SecondFlangeTypeDrop']").val(newValues);
    });
    document.getElementById("SecondFlangeTypeDrop").disabled = true;
});
```

The problem is if you select the "Full" option then you select one of the other 2 options "Half" or "Adapter" the function is still running. How do I get it to stop?

Comment: Would you please add you **HTML** code

Comment: So sounds like you would need to unbind the events. Or maybe think of a way to do it.

Comment: How do I unbind it?

Comment: `$("#myElement").on("change" ...)` to bind it, `$("#myElement").off("change");` to unbind it. For more, read: [`.off()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: What is "Half" and "Adapter"?

Comment: You can't select anything before all the JS is fully executed, hence no problem at hands here.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery. `$('#SecondFlangeTypeDrop')` instead of `document.getElementById("SecondFlangeTypeDrop")`

Comment: "Half" and "Adapter" are the other options on the part builder they are just normal buttons

Comment: You want to stop these functions when Half or Adapter enable?

Comment: Yes I want to stop these functions when Half or Adapter enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable these fields. If `.Half` and `.Adapter` are something like checkbox, then it can be done like that.

```
var $half = $(".Half");
var $adapter = $(".Adapter");

$(".Half, .Adapter").on("change", function(e){
    if($half.prop("checked") || $adapter.prop("checked")){
       $("input[name='FirstFlangeSystem']").prop( "disabled", true );
       $("input[name='FirstFlangeSystem']").prop( "disabled", true );
    }else{
       $("input[name='FirstFlangeSystem']").prop( "disabled", false );
       $("input[name='FirstFlangeSystem']").prop( "disabled", false );
    }
}
```